# How can I count the number of matched rows before limiting?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT u.id user_id,
       u.avatar,
       u.date_time,
       CONCAT(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname) name,
       sum($this->table_alias.vote_value) vote_value,
       sum($this->table_alias.score) score,
       $category_in_the_select AS tc $tag_in_the_select AS tt
FROM users u
JOIN reputations $this->table_alias ON u.id = $this->table_alias.owner_id $query_join
WHERE $time_limitation $query_where
GROUP BY user_id, u.avatar, u.date_time, name, tc, tt
ORDER BY score DESC, vote_value DESC
LIMIT :j, $this->per_page
```

It works as well and returns the expected result. Now I want to also calculate the number of total rows before limiting. Here is my new query which seems to work. I mean I'm not sure it works rightly, but tests say it works correctly:

```
SELECT x.*, @cnt cnt
FROM
  (SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) total,
          u.id user_id,
          u.avatar,
          u.date_time,
          CONCAT(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname) name,
          sum($this->table_alias.vote_value) vote_value,
          sum($this->table_alias.score) score,
          $category_in_the_select AS tc $tag_in_the_select AS tt
   FROM users u
   CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @cnt := 0) params
   JOIN reputations $this->table_alias ON u.id = $this->table_alias.owner_id $query_join
   WHERE $time_limitation $query_where
   GROUP BY user_id, u.avatar, u.date_time, name, tc, tt
   ORDER BY total) x
ORDER BY x.score DESC, x.vote_value DESC
LIMIT :j, $this->per_page
```

As you can see, I've used variables to count the result before applying the `LIMIT` clause.

Noted that, my approach works two time faster than `FOUND_ROWS()` function. Anyway, all I want to know, is my approach correct? Or there isn't any guarantee for it and I cannot rely on it?

Again, I've tested it and apparently worked correctly.

Comment: Yes, your approach works, but are you sure that you measured the times correctly? Could it be, that the data first had to be read into the buffer_pool? I find it hard to believe, that the `found_rows()` approach takes longer than your solution.